# Setting up CVCalendar via Cocoapods: Views Aren't Showing

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I've been trying to set up the CocoaPods `CVCalendar` for my app, but after integrating it into my Xcode project, the content fails to show through the `UIViews`. Essentially, whenever I connect the views to the `CVCalendarView` and `CVCalendarMenuView` variables, the views simply do not show. Here's the `ViewController` code I have so far, and help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import UIKit
import CVCalendar

class ViewController: UIViewController, CVCalendarViewDelegate, CVCalendarMenuViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var menuView: CVCalendarMenuView!

    @IBOutlet weak var calendarView: CVCalendarView!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        calendarView.commitCalendarViewUpdate()
        menuView.commitMenuViewUpdate()
    }
    func presentationMode() -> CalendarMode {
        return .MonthView
    }

    func firstWeekday() -> Weekday {
        return .Sunday
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Your ViewController class is the class in the storyboard?
- Did you hook up the delegates? [Delegate setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kU6Re.png)

  - You're delegating the rendering to your ViewController/
  - You need to drag to the yellow view controller nub.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason you'd like to setup CVCalendar manually you have to do the following steps.

[Refer here](https://github.com/Mozharovsky/CVCalendar#screenshots)